# Globally ignoring Verify.Http headers in snapshot

Tags: verify-tests

I'd like to hide some headers from the `HttpResponseMessage` snapshot. The documentation suggests using `await Verify(response).IgnoreMember("Authorization")` but I'd like to ignore it globally. I can do `VerifierSettings.IgnoreMembers("Authorization")` but this will ignore the property for **all** types not just in the headers. I can do the following for `HttpRequestMessage` and it works:

```cs
VerifierSettings.MemberConverter(typeof(HttpRequestMessage), "Headers", value =>
   ((Dictionary<string, object>)value)?
   .Where(k => k.Key.ToLowerInvariant() is not "authorization")
   .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value) is { Count: > 0 } headers ? headers : null);
```

This does not work for `HttpResponseMessage` because `Verify.Http`  does not use a regular converter for `HttpResponseMessage` (it registers one but it's never called due to the `File

```cs
        VerifierSettings.RegisterFileConverter<HttpResponseMessage>(
            (instance, _) => HttpResponseSplitterResult.Convert(instance));
        VerifierSettings
            .AddExtraSettings(serializer =>
            {
                var converters = serializer.Converters;
...snip...
                // This is called and can be customized via `MemberConverter`/`IgnoreMember`/etc..
                converters.Add(new HttpRequestMessageConverter());
                // This is never called because of the `RegisterFileConverter` above
                converters.Add(new HttpResponseMessageConverter());
```

Is there a way to ignore specific headers for `HttpResponseMessage` globally without ignoring it for all types? I have several headers to ignore that have fairly common names.